# What are the best practices for loading javascript with the least amount of impact on display performance of the page?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to download javascript without executing it?  I want to decrease my page load times so am trying to "lazy load" as much javascript onto the page while the user is idle.  However I don't want the javascript to execute, I just want it to be in the browser cache.

Should I use an object tag?  I noticed that I can use a LINK tag but that makes the browser think it's css which has a negative impact on my ui perf / responsiveness.

Comment: You want to slow the page-load time? ...could you not just incorporate a ridiculously large `.tiff` or `.bmp` and set it to `display: none;`? And what's your website, so that I can avoid it while using my mobile browser/phone bandwidth?

Comment: are you sure  you didn't mean 'decrease my page load times'?

Comment: Your efforts may be misguided. Usually placing scripts at the end of the body is enough, unless you have a special requirement?

Comment: "Decrease my page loads times" was correct.  Meaning I want to shorten the length of time (decrease) to when my page is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could load the file using the XMLHttpRequest object in JavaScript. (Aka AJAX). (end then of course just discard the result ^^).

Comment: But would this wouldn't add the file to the browser cache right?

Comment: @will: It should add the file to the cache if your http headers allow this.

Comment: I'm not sure this is considered best practice - while it may accomplish your goal of improving page load time (as in, the time Firefox/Chrome/IE tells the user the page is loading), which I'm not entirely sure it does, seems you are leveraging costs elsewhere - such as the overhead to perform an AJAX request. I'd have to see some sort of proof for the amount of speedup gained by doing this, I don't feel it's worth it.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have all code in functions or classes and nothing in global scope nothing will execute.

You can then start your script with a call from

```
window.load(function() {  //your initialisation here });
```

This will let the whole page load before running any scripts.

You could also add script references via script to make sure they load after any images in the page.

Just add a script element to head using script and it will load.
These pages has examples for this:

http://unixpapa.com/js/dyna.html

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml

This way if you have a slow connection or a sever that is overloaded, the visible elements will be loaded first by the browser.

Comment: +1 I believe this is a better way to architect client side code anyway.  Your execution shouldn't be based on arbitrary loading times that differ from session to session.

Comment: I think they mean "decrease" load times, by trying to avoid the execution pause when loading javascript and having it parsed and interpreted and compile and executed when nothing is happening anyway.

Comment: Changed the answer as the poster changed the question from increase to decrease ;)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no cross-browser compliant way to get around JavaScript loading in serial. If your javascript does something when it is loaded, you need to refactor your code. For instance, you don't write your jQuery commands/actions/code in the jQuery library script; you link the jQuery library and then put your jQuery commands into a separate file. You should do the same thing with your custom libraries. If this isn't possible, you have a big problem with the architecture of your code.

Also, make sure you stick non-executing JS at the bottom of the page near the `</body>` tag. This will allow everything else to load first, so that the bulky JS libraries don't slow down things like CSS and images.

Comment: I agree with this - I feel that rather than focusing on optimizing the code that's being loaded, the OP is focusing on how to improve loading it. A ton of Javascript that has to be loaded, executed and evaluated immediately is somewhat of a code smell. Rather than focusing on 20% of the issue (how the Javascript is loaded), focus on the 80% (what Javascript is loaded and why). Obviously an ideal, there are reasons the code is there, but you ask questions on SO for the ideal :)

Answer (score 1):

The best practices way to deal with external javascript is to have it load after everything else on the page by putting it at the bottom of the page. Then everything that can be rendered will be and display and then the javascript at the bottom of the page will load and be compiled and cached. Of course this only works if the javascipt is a library of functions that don't need to be executed mid-page, in that case, you are stuck with serial javascript loading compiling and execution regardless.

[Require.JS](http://requirejs.org/) is a great library for automatically managing when your javascript loads.

Comment: Thanks.  But my q was more about how to load, not when.  But thanks anyway.

Comment: when you load is the only thing that is important, there is only `inline` and `external`. if you want the least impact on the rest of the page, `load` or 'inline` all the javascript at the bottom of the page, that is the only way to not impact.